# Initial guess for babylonian method when calculating hypothenuse

Tags: trigonometry, newton-raphson

I have given side lengths $a$ and $b$ and wish to calculate hypothenuse $c$ using the Babylonian aka Newton-Raphson method for finding the square root of $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Since I know that $c^2$ is the result of adding $a^2$ and $b^2$ I figure there ought to be some clever way of using $a$ and $b$ to obtain a good initial guess for Babylonian.

Thus far the best I've come up with for my initial guess is $|a| + |b|$. Is there something even better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what operations are allowed. Without specifying it, [some crazy things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) are possible even without taking the square root itself as an initial guess.

We'll assume we are allowed to use basic arithmetical operations.
Without loss of generality, let $a>b>0$. Let $x=b/a$. Then $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a\sqrt{1+x^2}\approx a(1+x^2/2)$. So that is a good initial guess, especially if $x\ll1$. A more precise expansion can be obtained from Taylor series.

(Initially, this answer referred to another answer which is now gone, so I edited this one accordingly.)

Comment: Hmm... good point. Intuitively this improved initial guess should be obtained without defeating the purpose of doing Newton-Raphson afterwards. I'm unsure how to state this as a formal limitation however.

Comment: Are you sure that's $a(1+x^2/2) $? The other answer had it as $a(1+x/2) = a + b/2$, with $x$ not $x^2$.

Comment: @Wingblade Oh. It seems that I wasn't attentive enough and thought that the other answer was correct since it looked like correct, even though it wasn't. Anyway, in my answer, it's correct (compare to the next-to-last example in the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series ).

Comment: That wiki page also says $1 + x/2$, the $x^2$ is in the part of the series you dropped. My practical tests also confirm that $a + b/2$ works better than $a + b$.

Comment: @Wingblade Note that we have $x^2$ where wiki has $x$. When $a$ and $b$ are close to each other, there's little difference between $a(1+x^2/2)$ and $a+b/2$; when $x$ is very small, both formulas give approximately $a$; but $a(1+x^2/2)$ is the best option anyway.

Comment: The other answer just had $x$ there, they were using $a*\sqrt(1+x)$. Where's that square root rule from anyway? Might be the other answer misapplied it.

Comment: @Wingblade Well, we want a good approximation of $c$. Then $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \sqrt{a^2+a^2(b/a)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + a^2x^2} =$ $ \sqrt{a^2(1+x^2)} = \sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{1+x^2}=a\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Ah, now I understand where that came from. Thank you for your explanation! Your version does give _vastly_ better guesses than my or the other method. +1 and accepted.